# Third party controls and scripts

Tags: asp.net

Looking for a good resource to find asp.net controls and such. I don't mind purchasing them so open source is not my only consideration.

I have a social site that I want to build but I do not want to reinvent the wheel. Things like membership and user managment, banner ad managment, forums etc.. are common features in most any social site so i was hoping to purcahase that code.

I have considered DotNetNuke but this is a learning project and not every organization uses DNN so I figure I can learn things about ASP.Net dev by writng my own app that I would not by using DNN.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/), [ComponentArt](http://www.componentart.com/), [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/default.aspx), and [Karmasoft](http://www.karamasoft.com/Home.aspx). They all make some great control libraries, many for more than just ASP.NET.